# how to count two seperate where condition linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
<person>
<name>Mehmet</name>
<date>25.07.1974</date>
<region>M</region>
```

Let's assume there is a XML file which contains  and want to count
   - persons who's birthdate is prior 2000  and
   - person who's birthdate is prior 2000 and region M

I can get counts as below.

```
int x = List.Where( x=> x.Date < dateTime2000 ).Count();

int y = List.Where( x=> x.date < dateTime2000 && x.region == "M" ).Count();
```

Executions of aboves are fast.
But there are same comprasions and i feel it is not OK.
I do not calculate ToList() and ToArray() ,but i think above codes are more faster.
I am looking for faster alternative solution,if possible.
Thanks for answers

Comment: As you *have* to iterarte the whole collection at least once there´s no real difference on calling `Enumerable.Count` instead of `ToList().Count`. The actual question thus is not *wheather* to call `ToList` but *when*.

Comment: All answers are true.But according to me this is more suitable   List.Where( x=> x.Date < dateTime200)  .GroupBy(r=>r.Region)  .Select(g=>g.Count());

Answer (score 4):

You could use this:

```
var prior2000 = List.Where(x => x.Date < dateTime2000).ToList();
var x = prior2000.Count;
var y = prior2000.Count(x => x.region == "M");
```

This will only loop the results of the first query instead of all elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can count how many items in x have region equal to "M"

```
 var itemsBefore2000 =  List.Where( x=> x.Date < dateTime2000 ).ToArray();
 int x = itemsBefore2000.Length;
 int y = itemsBefore2000.Where( x=> x.region == "M" ).ToArray().Length; 
         // or
         itemsBefore2000.Count( x=> x.region == "M" ); // this one is preferable
```

P.S. I wonder why so many people like to use Lists instead of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could at least reuse the first query for both counts:

```
var birthPrio2000 = List.Where( x=> x.Date < dateTime2000 ).ToList();
int countBirthPrio2000 = birthPrio2000.Count;
int countBirthPrio2000RegionM = birthPrio2000.Count(x => x.region == "M");
```

Another approach that uses a lookup (similar to a dictionary):

```
var birthPrio2000Regions = List.Where(x => x.Date < dateTime2000).ToLookup(x => x.Region);
int prio2000_TotalCount = birthPrio2000Regions.Sum(g => g.Count());
int prio2000_RegionM_Count = birthPrio2000Regions["M"].Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to ensure that the source is iterated only once you can use the `.Aggregate()` function and do the logic on yourself:

```
var desiredValues = persons.Aggregate(
    new { All = 0, InRegion = 0 }, 
    (sum, person) => new
    {
        All = person.Date < dateTime2000 ? sum.All + 1 : sum.All,
        InRegion = person.Region == "M" ? sum.InRegion + 1 : sum.InRegion
    });

var prio2000_TotalCount = desiredValues.All;
var prio2000_RegionM_Count = desiredValues.InRegion;
```